# OpenGL transparent object behind another transparent object

Tags: opengl, transparency

I'm trying to render grass leaves. The simple way is to draw two parallel quads crossing in the middle like this

[image]

The problem is that the first quad to be rendered won't be transparent for the next grass leaf to be drawed. If I draw A then B, B won't show behind A

[image]

This is how i'm rendering

```
void drawHighGrass(){
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.95);


glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);


glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturas[HIGH_GRASS]);

glCullFace(GL_FRONT);

glPushMatrix();
//glTranslatef(1000, 0, 1000);
glScalef(1, 1.5, 1);

glPushMatrix();

glTranslatef(-100 / 2, -10, 0);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(100, 0, 0);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(100, 40, 0);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(0, 40, 0);
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(100, 0, 0);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(0, 40, 0);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(100, 40, 0);
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
//glTranslatef(1000, 0, 1000);
glTranslatef(0, -10, -100 / 2);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(0, 0, 100);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(0, 40, 100);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(0, 40, 0);
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(0, 0, 100);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(0, 40, 0);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(0, 40, 100);
glEnd();

glPopMatrix();
glPopMatrix();

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

glCullFace(GL_BACK);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER, 0.5);
glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
```